# Greek forums on Ubuntu

Tags: discussion

Is there a Greek language                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         section on this forum. I have built a PC with Ubuntu 12.04 and sent to my friend in Zakynthos. He wants to learn how to build programs and applications. He is a native Greek speaker and it would be good for him to catch up with others who speak Greek and use Ubuntu

Answer (score 8):

This page is a question & answer page in english, not a forum.

If you want to use a greek forum try this :

[greek forum ubuntu](https://forum.ubuntu-gr.org/)